# Merge 2 pdf byte arrays into 1

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext

I trying to create a Function the merges 2 byte() pdfs into 1 pdf byte

My code currently creates 2 byte arrays from 2 different sources and I would like to merge them into 1 document as a byte array. (Very summarised code below)

```
Function MergerPDF (pdf1 as byte(), pdf2 as byte()) as byte

'Merger 2 PDF byte arrays

'Return merged byte array

End Function
```

It is only ever going to be 2 into 1

Thanks in advance for any help, I'm a little stuck on this one :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question insinuates that you are taking one PDF as a byte array and that you want to glue another the bytes of another PDF to that first byte array. It is unclear what you want to achieve with this, unless you want to create a corrupt PDF file.

Could it be that you want to concatenate two documents into one. For instance a document with 10 pages and a document with 5 pages, resulting in a document with 15 pages.

In that case, you haven't done much research, because I've asked my publisher to make [Chapter 6 of my book](http://manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf) available for free. After reading this chapter, you'll understand that you're looking for classes named `PdfReader` to read the bytes of the existing PDFs and `PdfCopy` (or `PdfSmartCopy` depending on the nature of the PDFs) to concatenate the documents.

The examples of chapter 6 are available in [Java](http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=6) and [C#](http://tinyurl.com/itextsharpIIA2C06). More Java examples can be found in the [sandbox](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/merge).

This code snippet creates a PDF file in memory:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
  // step 1
  using (Document document = new Document()) {
    // step 2
    using (PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, ms)) {
      // step 3
      document.Open();
      // step 4
      for (int i = 0; i < pdf.Count; ++i) {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf[i]);
        // loop over the pages in that document
        int n = reader.NumberOfPages;
        for (int page = 0; page < n; ) {
          copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(reader, ++page));
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In your case, the `pdf` variable could be an array of byte arrays.

Use major keywords such as `PdfReader`, `PdfCopy`, iTextSharp to find more examples. It is in your interest to accept this answer fast because your question is eligible to be closed and/or downvoted. The rule on StackOverflow is that you should do some effort before asking a question and your question could be considered of being of "poor quality" by the community. A common comment on questions like yours is "What have you tried?"